# Read specific values from quaternion

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I want to read the following values from a Unity Quaternion https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html

If x rotation (pitch) is 180 (alternatively 0)

If y rotation (roll) is 180 (alternatively 0)

What is the most performant formula to get the z rotation (yaw)?

I found this formula online to get z axis, is this the most performant? 
z = qz / sqrt(1-qw*qw)
http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/quaternionToAngle/

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's your use case where you need to determine a thousand or more angles every frame?

Comment: @Serlite 1000 times per frame was an exaggeration to promote understanding that performance is very important. I need it for non-axis aligned collision detection where a rectangular collider is involved. Why I'm making an extra system on top of Unity's is for a very specific and complicated reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula I posted was a conversion from quaternion to angle and axis. What I needed was quaternion to euler angles. I realized I didn't need x and y angles anyway.

Found some code online and shaped it to suit my needs, this converts only the z angle to radians (1.3 ms 10K iterations)

```
public double GetZAngle(Quaternion q1)
{
    double sqw = q1.w * (double)q1.w;
    double sqx = q1.x * (double)q1.x;
    double sqy = q1.y * (double)q1.y;
    double sqz = q1.z * (double)q1.z;
    double unit = sqx + sqy + sqz + sqw; // If normalized is one, otherwise is correction factor
    double test = (double)q1.x * q1.y + (double)q1.z * q1.w;
    if (test > 0.499 * unit) // Singularity at north pole
        return Math.PI / 2;
    if (test < -0.499 * unit) // Singularity at south pole
        return -Math.PI / 2;
    return Math.Asin(2 * test / unit);
}
```

There is no clear pattern to just distinguish if the x and y angles were 0, but there is a code snippet here shows how to retrieve all of them in radians (2.14 ms 10K iterations (faster than Unity's 3 ms)) http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/quaternionToEuler/

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to use complex formula in order to read a value from a Quaternion. Unity already did it for you!

The easiest way is to read the **Euler Angle** of the *Quaternion* like this:

```
Vector3 angle = rotation.eulerAngles;
```

The you can read each rotation easily `angle.x`, ...

Comment: Sorry should have said why I'm doing this. Quaternion.eulerAngles is converted in one long operation, this is an expensive operation when done up to 1000 times every 1/60 of a second (3 ms for 10000 iterations). I just need to know if x and y axes are 180 and read z angle. When you only need one angle, all of them are converted which is an optimization flaw from Unity's side generally because it isn't 2D optimized.

Comment: @Martin Ho! was not aware of that. Thank you for your precision